# When I try to add a link to text in Google Sheets it glitches and creates this green line. How do I get it to stop doing that?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

In Google Sheets, I hit some setting and now every time I try to add a link to text it formats with this strange green highlighted line (inside green box). Once this line appears, it carries over to every other sheet and won't go away.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried looking up different settings for link text in Google Sheets but couldn't find anything related to this green line.